# Уточнение шаблона функции

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Ясного неба!

Читаю учебник по с++. Там есть пример уточнения шаблона класса:

```
template<typename T> class MyCout
{
    private:
        T data;
    public:
        MyCout(T a): data(a) {};
        void display() {cout << data << endl;};
};

template<> class MyCout<string>
{
    private:
        string data;
    public:
        MyCout(string a): data(a){};
        void display() {cout << data.c_str() << endl;};
};
```

Я решил поэкспериментировать, и немного укоротить код, сделав шаблон не целого класса, а только функции:

```
class NewCout
{
    public:
        NewCout(){};
        template<typename T> void display(T a){cout << a << endl;};
        template<> void display<string>(string a){cout << a.c_str() << endl;};
};
```

Но компилятор выдает ошибку на строке №6: **invalid explicit specialization before '>' token**.
Что я делаю не так?

---

И еще вопрос вдогонку: как принято оформлять шаблоны?

Comment: template<> ?

Comment: @klopp, ну с классами всё нормально:  

    template<typename T> class MyCout
    ... 
    template<> class MyCout<string>
    ...  

В книге:  
Шаблоны функций можно уточнять точно таким же образом.  
Синтаксис следующий: 
    templateo типВозвращаемогоЗначения имяФункции <_особыйТип_>(аргументы) {} 
Здесь _особыйТип_ - тип данных, с которым работает уточненный шаблон.

Comment: А кто автор учебника? Судя по всему, там ошибка.

Comment: "Я решил поэкспериментировать, и немного укоротить код, сделав шаблон не целого класса, а только функции:" - судя по этому автор ТС, книжка не причем.

Comment: @IronVbif, читаем мой последний комментарий со сноской из учебника.  
@VladD, Книга "Программирование на С++. Дирк Хенкеманс, Марк Ли 2002". И да, в учебнике полно ошибок - то переменную не ту напишут, то точку с запятой не поставят, и тд и тп. Может издание такое попалось...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C++ запрещает частичную специализацию методов, только шаблоны классов могут быть специализированы. См. [стандарт](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf), параграф 14.5.6. Почему именно так было сделано, обсуждается [здесь](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm) (ворнинг: инглиш лэнгвидж инсайд!).

Судя по всему, автор книги не прав.

Вы можете, однако, *перегрузить* шаблонный метод (что не то же самое).

---

Ох, позор мне. Вот [это](http://ideone.com/PHaodb) работает:

```
class C
{
public:
    template<typename T>
    void f(T t);
};

template<typename T>
void C::f(T t)
{
    cout << t << endl;
}

template<>
void C::f<int>(int t)
{
    cout << "(int specialization) " << t << endl;
}
```

---

Разобрался. В примере над чертой не *частичная*, а *полная* специализация. Частичная специализация всё-таки запрещена, как и говорит спецификация. [Пример](http://ideone.com/HuXlOP):

```
class C
{
public:
    template<typename T>
    void f(T t);
};

template<typename T>
void C::f(T t)
{
    cout << t << endl;
}

template<typename T> // ошибка: function template partial 
void C::f<T*>(T* pt) // specialization ‘f<T*>’ is not allowed
{
    cout << "(pointer specialization) " << *pt << endl;
}
```

Comment: Внутри класса не получается сделать специализацию шаблона метода, но когда выношу шаблон и его уточнение из класса, то все нормально компилируется. Может это и имел ввиду автор книги...

Comment: @teanЫЧ: хм, и правда: <http://ideone.com/Eg17mO>, <http://ideone.com/ObGE9k>. Сейчас расследую...

Comment: @teanЫЧ: Простите, ввёл вас в заблуждение, посыпаю голову пеплом. Обновил ответ.

Comment: @teanЫЧ: Частично реабилитировался.

Comment: большое спасибо)  
Просто убираю определение специализации из класса, и пишу её реализацию. И всё компилируется.

Comment: @teanЫЧ: угу — в случае полной специализации.

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант вынести специализации вне класса

```
class NewCout
{
    public:
       NewCout(){};
       template<typename T> void display(T a){cout << a << endl;};
};

template<> void NewCout::display<string>(string a){cout << a.c_str() << endl;};
```

Не знаю насколько это правильное решение, как по мне вся эта шаблонная магия от лукавого. Тем более что специализация шаблона в таком тривиальном случае и не нужна

```
class NewCout
{
public:
    NewCout(){};
    template<typename T> void display(T a){cout << a << endl;};
    void display(string a){cout << a << endl;};
};
```

Answer (score -2):

```
template<> void display(string a){cout << a.c_str() << endl;};
```

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?