# Почему запрещена частичная специализация шаблонных функций?

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

```
template<typename T>
void f(){}

template<typename T>
void f<T*>(){}
```

> function template partial specialization 'f' is not allowed

Почему разрешена только полная специализация функции? Как то это не правильно, для классов разрешено, можно и функции рассматривать как отдельные модули. Конечно, перегрузку никто не отменял, но вдруг мне не нужны аргументы функции?

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/210840/10105

Comment: @VladD: Свое я выше сообщение удалил - бред. Правило выбора шаблона я понимаю. Но я все равно не могу никак понять почему запретили перегрузку по шаблонам частичной специализации. Отрывок из статьи: "Коммитет указал, что было бы удивительно, если бы только из за того что вы написали специализацию для некоторого шаблона, изменялся бы выбор используемого шаблона". Изменился бы выбор используемого шаблона в сторону более специализированного по описанным правилам, это же перегрузка.

Comment: Для начала, есть лёгкий обходной путь: [частичная специализация класса + статическая функция + wrapper](http://therobotsbrain.blogspot.de/2012/10/partial-template-specialization-for.html). Herb Sutter пишет в статье [_Why Not Specialize Function Templates?_](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm), что он не рекомендует даже полную специализацию из-за проблем с выбором между специализацией и перегрузкой («The Dimov/Abrahams Example»). Вот в [_этом обсуждении_](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5101516/276994) говорят, что это просто недочёт стандарта.

Comment: Поэтому мне кажется, что недочёт не будут исправлять.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Частичная специализация шаблонов функций рассматривалась в рамках задачи #229,
[которая была отклонена и закрыта](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_closed.html#229) в [n2173](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2173.html).

Рекомендуемая альтернатива - это перегрузка функций.
В случае если параметр шаблона не привязан к аргументу функции, ее надо делать статической функцией шаблонного класса.